# Printing words from a text

Tags: python, regex, text

I've made this Python program for printing words from a text but I got stuck where Python reaches the next 'tab' index it returns to the initial one when it checks the conditional and I don't know why, so can anyone explain to me why it doesn't take the new 'tab' index?

```
import re

initial_text = '@ Traditionally, a text is understood to be a piece of written or spoken material in its primary form (as opposed to a paraphrase or summary). A text is any stretch of language that can be understood in context. It may be as simple as 1-2 words (such as a stop sign) or as complex as a novel. Any sequence of sentences that belong together can be considered a text.'
text = re.sub('\W+', ' ', initial_text)
t = -1
for i in text:
    n = text.find(i)
    if i == ' ':
         print(text[t+1:n])
         t = n
```

Comment: could you post the complete code including 'text'?

Comment: What is text and `tab` index ? Please explain you question a little bit

Comment: Tab character is '\t' if that is what you are looking for

Comment: You want to get words from text ?

Comment: @Prakhar yes exactly.

Comment: @David using regex is an overkill here , use text.split(), you can refer the answer

Comment: @Prakhar I've used regex for removing punctuations (!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~), I mean I can not do that with split() right? then after removing them I will use split() for getting words.

Comment: @David ok you haven't mentioned that earlier, check the updated answer

Comment: If you are using `re` then simply `re.split()` would be more direct than using `re.sub()` and then splitting on the resulting string.

Comment: @JohnColeman I've used it and I got some problems, could you please explain how?

Comment: @David What problems did you have?  `for word in re.split('\W+',initial_text): print(word)` works as expected. (That is using your regular expression. If it doesn't quite split where you want, that is a different question).

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach

```
import re

initial_text = "whatever your text is"
text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', initial_text)

words_list = text.split()
for word in words:
    print(word)
```

Explanation using an example :

```
import re

initial_text = "Hello : David welcome to Stack ! overflow"
text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', initial_text)
```

Above piece removes the punctuations

```
words_list = text.split()
```

`words_list` after this step will be : ['Hello', 'David', 'welcome', 'to', 'Stack', 'overflow']

```
for word in words_list:
    print(word)
```

Above code takes each element from the list and prints it.

Comment: Oh, yes I've forgotten this method. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: But can I print them without storing them in a list? because it's something additional.

Comment: This is the simplest and standard approach for extracting words from a string in Python. And using list is `additional` , in what sense ?

Comment: could you please explain this pattern r'[^\w\s]' and how it removes punctuation in another word what it means? and what’s the difference between it and '\W+' and '[^A-za-z0-9]+'.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the `find()` function, this will return the index number of the first occurrence of the word you are searching, that's why it is again moving to the first index.

You can refer to the `find()` function [documentation](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/find.html).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use

```
import re

initial_text = '@ Traditionally, a text is understood to be a piece of written or spoken material in its primary form (as opposed to a paraphrase or summary). A text is any stretch of language that can be understood in context. It may be as simple as 1-2 words (such as a stop sign) or as complex as a novel. Any sequence of sentences that belong together can be considered a text.'
words = re.findall(r'[^\W_]+', initial_text)
for word in words:
    print(word)
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##TZE9T8NADIb3/ApvTQVEAjakSjCyIzHwUbmJm5xI7MPn0ObXB18iUG@ybJ/f57XjZJ3w/TyHIYoaKBVF4GAB@73R2WAHm0d4UWw8J4x9P10DwlIKCUZuSJOJNGACB/JSDFQTyBFOGsyIQRRSlC@PBjRSnwyBIViCqGFAneAoOkCJCSRGSbTM8kGoGDvFRMuIcci92wqe/tWRJ0imZHWXBXvkdsSWwDo0qJEz0AWhq9bC@XMFz@Y000KcILn5folub@7gJNokKNPoUz2FLiHRe1reZhBP1ZL7z2uV5Yd6p8os9D0Sr@4TuZLHaaU5UC/curGWrCP9o3OeFBzQPa9LrTbFqr/zU1THwI2vvNTN2@f76/7janMNl9fZFr66BTibWz4@FODPN8tW5sR2nn8B).

`re.findall` extracts all non-overlapping matches from the given text.

`[^\W_]+` is a regular expression that matches one or more characters different from non-word and underscores, and that means it matches substrings that consist of digits or/and letters only (all, ASCII and other Unicode).

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/8q2f8l/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
  [^\W_]+                  any character except: non-word characters
                           (all but a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _), '_' (1 or more
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
```